# Jekyll subfolders in collection

Tags: html, jekyll

I want to put `md` files in a collection `_notes`, but group them in folders. A big `html` of a topic will be generated from multiple `md` files.

Here is my attempt

```
_notes
 ├-database.md
 └-compiler.md
_note_sections
 ├-database
 | ├-indexing.md
 | └-concurrency.md
 └-compiler
   ├-assembly.md
   └-parsing.md
-layouts
 ├-note.html
 └-note_section.html
```

Each `md` file in `_notes_sections` stores the actual content and has layout `note_section` e.g.

```
---
section_title: xxx
layout: note_section
---

Testing text
{% highlight python %}
dfs_r(Node n, MBR w)...
{% endhighlight %}
```

Each `md` file in `_notes` combines multiple note_sections by showing them from expandible arrows and has layout `note`, here is the layout file `note.html`:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include mathjax.html %}
{% assign subfolder = 'compiler/' %}
<ul class="note_sections">
  {% for note_section in site.note_sections %} {% if note_section.relative_path contains subfolder %}
  <li>
    <details>
      <summary>{{note_section.section_title}}</summary>
      {{note_section.content}}
    </details>
  </li>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

while `note_section.html` is simply

```
---
layout: default
---
{{content}}
```

However, when generating the `html` into `_site/notes`, the `compiler.html` simply has the raw markdown content

```
.
.
.
<li>
  <details>
    Testing text
    {% highlight python %}
    dfs_r(Node n, MBR w)...
    {% endhighlight %}
    </details>
</li>
.
.
.
```

instead of turning the note_section markdowns into `html` which would turn the code snippet in markdown into these long `html` tags

```
<figure class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-python" data-lang="python"><span class="nf">
```

However, I do get a `_site/note_sections/compiler/assembly.html` file with the correct `html` generated from the note_section markdown. It is what I want to put inside the big topic html under `notes`, not just put the raw markdown inside.

Answer (score 0):

This one took me a while to figure out what was happening... I *think* that collections are NOT meant to be rendered directly as pages... meaning they need to be referenced from another actual page.

So I think this is an easy fix... you either need a new page that references the _notes, or you could convert the _notes files into pages themselves.

The documentation is not explicit about this... limitation?... but it's the feeling I get about how these are "supposed" to work: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/